# How to create clean url for Default page in Yii2 urlManager

Tags: php, routes, yii2, yii-url-manager

My index rules like as below:

```
[
    'pattern' => 'page/<page:\d+>',
    'route' => 'site/index',
],
```

it work, but in pagination, firest page is `example/page/1`, i change rules as below:

```
[
    'pattern' => 'page/<page:\d+>',
    'route' => 'site/index',
    'defaults' => ['page' => 1],
],
```

Now first page has become to `example.com/page`.

How write rules, to first page in pagination show like `example.com`?

Comment: So you want `example.com/page/1` route to be accessed via url `example.com`, then later pages via `example.com/page/2`, `example.com/page/3` etc?

Comment: Yes, that's right.

Comment: OK, in your main config do you have a default route configured as: `'defaultRoute' => 'site/index'` ?

Comment: `example.com` now open site/index, my problem is when in `example.com/page/2` click on previous page in pagination, instead example.com opened example.com/page

Comment: OK, I have an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per your question in conjunction with your comments, I suggest that you additionally add a rule for a blank url pattern, i.e. for url with domain only, that is directed to your `defaultRoute` with a default `$page` parameter value.

```
'rules' => [
    [
        'pattern' => '',
        'route' => 'site/index',
        'defaults' => ['page' => 1],
    ],
    [
        'pattern' => 'page/<page:\d+>',
        'route' => 'site/index',
    ],
],
```

Then, in your controller action you can test this url rule is working as follows:

```
public function actionIndex($page)
{
    echo '<pre>';
    echo 'site / index / $page ' . print_r($page, true);
    echo '</pre>';
    exit;
}
```

Also note that you could set the default in the method declaration of your controller action like so:

```
public function actionIndex($page = 1)
{
    echo '<pre>';
    echo 'site / index / $page ' . print_r($page, true);
    echo '</pre>';
    exit;
}
```

Which would allow you to simplify your config as follows:

```
'rules' => [
    [
        'pattern' => '',
        'route' => 'site/index',
    ],
    [
        'pattern' => 'page/<page:\d+>',
        'route' => 'site/index',
    ],
],
```

Comment: Excellent, glad to help!

Comment: Configuring default values for route params as a parameters in action method is tricky and can be considered as a code smell. It will not work as expected if you will try create URL by `Url::to(['site/index', 'page' => 1])`.

Comment: True, I don't like to use action defaults, hence why the better option listed first